# No matching version found for require-from-string@^1.1.0

Tags: angularjs, npm, bower, npm-install

Dependencies for npm project:

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular-chart.js": "1.1.0",
    "angular-cookies": "1.5.7",
    "angular-ui-bootstrap": "2.4.0",
    "angular-ui-grid": "4.0.5",
    "checklist-model": "0.10.0",
    "json-schema": "0.2.2"
  }
```

And `npm install` stops to work with the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for require-from-string@^1.1.0
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget 
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'cosmiconfig'
npm ERR! notarget
```

How to fix it?

Comment: i have the same problem right now...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's an [open incident](https://status.npmjs.org/) with the npm registry.

Details on the incident:

> Several packages including "require-from-string" are currently
>   unavailable. We are aware of the issue and are working to restore the
>   affected user and packages. Please do not attempt to republish
>   packages, as this will hinder our progress in restoring them.  Jan 6,
>   19:45 UTC

Comment: It's working fine now, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[image]

**some problem with NPM registry some of the packages got deleted.
They are restoring it... it will be available shortly**

Temp solution get the package from already running projects/older projects

for ***require-from-string*** package can use below link
npm install https://github.com/floatdrop/require-from-string/tarball/v1.1.0

Answer (score 1):

ng serve causes problem now
Versions of @angular/compiler-cli and typescript could not be determined.
The most common reason for this is a broken npm install.

Please make sure your package.json contains both @angular/compiler-cli and typescript in
devDependencies, then delete node_modules and package-lock.json (if you have one) and
run npm install again.